# Do plain cmake packages need to handle pkg-config file generation?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@joq and I are working on improving the current [libsegwayrmp release](https://github.com/segwayrmp/libsegwayrmp-release/tree/release/groovy/libsegwayrmp) from @William.

It seems like the current release does not generate a pkg-config file. Consequently, any dependency on this package fails. On the other hand, the [libfreenect release](https://github.com/ros-drivers-gbp/libfreenect-release/tree/release/groovy/libfreenect) works fine, as pkg-config file generation was already handled upstream. This worked out of the box while building the package with catkin_make_isolated.

Should I setup libsegwayrmp to do something similar? Or is there an alternative I am not aware about?

Thanks!!

**Edit #1**

Based on @William's answer, here's a second question. Can a rosbuild package depend on a plain-cmake package? If yes, then can it use find_package or only pkg-config is supported? This is the error I get trying to build segway_rmpX (currently dry) with the current libsegwayrmp wet release.

```
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only segway_rmpX
Package libsegwayrmp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libsegwayrmp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61623/do-plain-cmake-packages-need-to-handle-pkg-config-file-generation?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-26**:
I am pretty sure they do. Most Linux libraries already have that implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`libsegwayrmp` is not a `catkin` package. Therefore it does not require a `pkg-config`.  There are `find_package` files provided by `libsegwayrmp` for depending projects to find and use it:

```
find_package(libsegwayrmp REQUIRED)

...

include_directories(${libsegwayrmp_INCLUDE_DIRS})

...

target_link_libraries(my_executable ${libsegwayrmp_LIBRARIES})
```

You can see the (simplistic) implementation file here:

https://github.com/segwayrmp/libsegwayrmp/blob/master/cmake/Findsegwayrmp.cmake

That being said it would be nice to have `pkg-config` files for `libsegwayrmp`.

**Update:**

Yes, a rosbuild package can depend on a plain CMake project. You just have to treat `libsegwayrmp` like you would any other third party library (Boost, Eigen, VTK). You should not list `libsegwayrmp` as a ros package dependency, but rather as a rosdep dependency.

**Update2:**

However, to remain backwards compatible (preventing a need to change `segway_rmpx`) would be to add pkg-config files to `libsegwayrmp`.  I forgot until now that REP-0136 has a note about this:

http://ros.org/reps/rep-0136.html#backwards-compatibility

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-27**:
Does that only work when the library is installed into /usr  or /usr/local?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-04-27**:
@William: Thanks for your answer. I have added a second question to the original one. Either way, we were planning on catkinizing everything so it does not matter if segway_rmpX is using rosbuild for the moment.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-04-29**:
@William: Thanks! This gives us all the information we need to proceed.